# How to test functions using File.Create() and File.Delete() methods in xunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

I haven't been coding for too long, so apologies if this isn't articulated very well.

So, I've been trying to get my head around using constructors and `IDisposable` in order to write unit tests in xunit that test some functions relating to creating and deleting files.  Initially I started writing tests without any sort of 'setup'/'teardown' equivalent, but I ran into the problem of tests passing on first run, but failing second time round as the file I was testing could be deleted had already been deleted in the previous instance of running the test!  So, now I'm trying to include 'File.Create("file-path")', 'File.Delete("file-path")' type methods in my constructor, but find that my tests all break as soon as I incorporate one of these methods.  This doesn't happen with 'Directory.CreateDirectory()', or 'Directory.Delete()'.

To exemplify, here is an example of the sort of thing I have been trying with the constructor...

```
 public class SetUp : IDisposable
{  
    protected SetUp() 
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\Projects\Tests\Test");
        File.Create(@"c:\Projects\Tests\test.txt");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Directory.Delete(@"c:\Projects\Tests\Test", true);
        File.Delete(@"c:\Projects\Tests\test.txt");
    }
}
```

This is necessary for the following test:

```
[Theory]
    [InlineDataAttribute(@"c:\Projects\Tests\test3.txt")]
    public void CanRemoveFile(string filePath)
    {
        //Assign
        var myInstanceOfApphelper = new AppHelper();
        bool fileExists = true;
        //Act
        myInstanceOfApphelper.RemoveFile(filePath);
        fileExists = myInstanceOfApphelper.CheckFileExists(filePath);
        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(false, fileExists);
    }
```

...as without this constructor part to create the file before running the tests, there will be no file at that location to delete next time I run the test, and it will fail.  However, as soon as I include the line `File.Create(@"c:\Projects\Tests\test.txt");`, all of my tests break.  The errors I am returned are all

> "The process cannot access the file 'c:\Projects\Tests\test.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process."

but I can't understand this as most of the tests don't use 'c:\Projects\Tests\test.txt anyway!

Can anyone tell me why this won't work?  How could I go about testing the creation and deletion of files in the xunit framework in such away that the tests consistently pass?  Can you point out any obvious errors with the way I've written this?

Comment: How do you use your `Setup` class?  I don't see that you actually are using it in the test.

Comment: I have sometimes run into similar problems.  I found that using the `System.IO.FileInfo` object to create and delete files worked better than using the static `File.Create` and `File.Delete` methods.

Comment: You also might check that the directory isn't read-only, as it will usually be if it's where VS is putting your compiled executables.

Comment: @AnnL. Would you mind expanding on how to use the setup class in the tests?  I implement the class in the test class, is there something else I need to do with the individual tests?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you.  Are you still having difficulties?

Comment: Nope, I got it in the end.  I ended up with a TestFixture class that sets up and disposes of file steams within that.  Seems to work fine now!

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you describe means that you keep a handle on the file between two tests. I suggest you double check the way your setup and teardown works because it seems like you're doing it wrong (not calling them before and after each tests).

Bonus: I recommend not using the real file system while doing unit tests. There are in memory file systems which allows to completely clean your workspaces and be sure you are not bothered by the physical file system.

For instance check: https://github.com/bobvanderlinden/sharpfilesystem

Comment: Forgive me if this is an incredibly simple question, but could you point me in the right direction for how to call the setup and teardown in the tests?  At the moment, I am implementing the SetUp in my test class, but doing nothing for each individual test that uses setup and teardown.  I can't see anything obvious in the examples I've been able to find that shows how to do this!

Comment: In xunit the setup is doone in the class constructor and the teardown is done in the dispose methode (implements IDisposable). Their documentation is quite clear, they discourage setup and teardown principle. I disagree but it's my own opinion. I prefer using Nunit which is more powerfull.